# Sound from Youtube and the like can't be heard through earphones

Tags: sound

Ubuntu 20.04.6

[image]

When in Settings, I can test my earphones. That is if I press any buttons marked by the arrows in the scrieenshot, I can hear the sounds both in the left and in the right earpiece.

But I can't hear any sound in my earphones when playing Youtube or anything else.

I also have loudspeakers plugged in. And Youtube's sound goes to one channel of them only. As far as I remember, they are in good condition. That is they both should produce sound.

When earphones are plugged in, the sound should be directed to them automatically.
And like that it was just recently.

Could you help me?